# How can I write the registry with administrator permission?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a new registry using this code:

```vb
Dim r As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegEditAuditor, True)
r.SetValue("Actualizar", StartupPath + "\Actualizar")
RegActualizar = r.GetValue("Actualizar", "")
r.Close()
```

But when I execute my application I get an error that I think its about permission, because if I execute as administrator it works fine.

Comment: Could you include the error message in your question?

Comment: Are you logged into Windows as an admin when running the app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit **LOCAL MACHINE** registry,
Which requires **administrative** access,
So you have 2 choices here:

## 1) Make assembly always RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR

You can make your assembly to always **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR**.,
By adding the **Manifest File**

Right click your **project file** on the **Solution Explorer**,
Select `Add`, then `New item` (or CTRL+SHIFT+A),
There you can find `Application Manifest File`,
[image]
Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

## 2) Change LocalMachine to CurrentUser (Recommended)

```
Dim r As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegEditAuditor, True)
r.SetValue("Actualizar", StartupPath + "\Actualizar")
RegActualizar = r.GetValue("Actualizar", "")
r.Close()
```